# Sony VAIO webcam shows brownish colors

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, webcam

I just bought a Sony VAIO VPCF23N1E and webcam colours are quite black & white like (all very brownish).

I reinstalled Windows because with all the factory pre-installed stuff – it was showing too many blue screens and other weird stuff.

In Device Manager, I can see only "USB2.0 Camera" (in *Properties* the manufacturer is Microsoft, so I guess it's some generic driver). Anybody knows how can I find out the real name of my webcam, because I want to find its drivers?

Lastly, how can I fix these colors?

Comment: You should provide a screen shot.  There is a world of difference between "black and white" and "brown monochromatic" since brown is a color typically not seen in black and white.  If your camera is simply showing in reduced colors, it may not be a driver issue.  It may be a camera issue, or a lighting issue, etc.

Comment: .. or a sepia toned filter applied by the software you are using to view the camera...

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and the Sony people say that there is no problem with the webcam. I think there is some problem with the Exmor camera.

I found temporary solution though: First, install ArcSoft Magic-i Visual Effects. It may be already installed on your PC. Start it, then in configuration set gain to 2 and saturation to 100, then start any camera application to see quality.

It will definitely improve.

Answer (score 1):

On my VGN-FW54M there is also the generic driver installed. I tested the camera using Skype and it works without problems. So there is no need for another driver, is it?

Comment: my camera works, but it's all black and white, no colours

Comment: Here are all the drivers, the webcam is a "HD web camera powered by "Exmor"": http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VPCF23N1E_B/updates

Comment: "The camera driver is not available in the 'Preinstalled Drivers' section for recent VAIO models, because the bundled Windows driver is used.  Typically Windows should be able to locate the driver on its own.", http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VPCF23N1E_B/tips-and-solutions

Comment: it works but as i said it's black and white